# Batch file to rename folders with wildcard or create a new folder and move contents?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wildcard, batch-processing

I'm trying to tidy up a data folder and have written a batch file to take care of a lot of preliminary work (delete empty folders, delete junk files, etc), but I'm falling over when trying to deal with files within duplicate folders.

This is an example of the current situation:

```
w:\Data\Corporations\555\20130101\Concat_000001\555_20130101_data.zip
w:\Data\Corporations\555\20130101\Concat_000002\555_20130101_data.zip
w:\Data\Corporations\555\20130101\Concat_000003\555_20130101_data.zip
w:\Data\Corporations\555\20130101\Concat_000004\555_20130101_data.zip
```

There should only be one Concat folder per YYYYMMDD folder, and should look like this:

```
w:\Data\Corporations\555\20130101\Concat\555_20130101_data.zip
```

There are hundreds of folders in w:\Data\Corporations to be processed, so I figure I need to first of all find any folder named Concat_*, make a folder named Concat within the same parent folder, and then move any *zip from Concat_* to Concat.

I have tried various combinations of `FOR /D in (Concat_*)` with `MD` and `MOVE` commands, but with no luck so far. I've also tried calling a subroutine from the `FOR` statement that would jump back a level in the tree, create a folder named Concat, go back to Concat_* and move the .zip files, but again with no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Pete

Comment: At http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754900(v=ws.10).aspx, you can find some documentation how you can extract the file name only or the extension only or the directory part of file name variables in a for loop in batch files.

Comment: Windows PowerShell should have the power to achieve this.

Comment: and what with the ZIPs with the same name? Move overwrites the files with same names.

Comment: Thanks for the link @FrankPl, I'll have a look through that. I think it's going to prove too complex for my incredibly basic grasp of the commands though!

Comment: @Endoro - the .zip files with the same name are all the same. A different process outside of my control sometimes creates duplicate files. Rather than write these to the same folder (Concat), it creates a duplicate folder with a reference number appended (Concat_00001). My goal in this processing is precisely to overwrite the zip files with their duplicates, so I'm left with the correct folder with one final copy of the zip file, and all the Concat_* folders empty to be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does what you asked. If you uncomment the last line, then empty config_* folders will be removed. Non-empty config_* folders will be preserved.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /ad /s concat_*') do (
  if not exist "%%~dpFconcat\" mkdir "%%~dpFconcat\"
  if exist "%%F\*.zip" move /y "%%F\*.zip" "%%~dpFconcat\" >nul
  REM uncomment line below if you want to remove empty concat_* folders
  REM dir /b "%%F"|findstr "^" >nul || rd "%%F"
)
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much! It turns out I wasn't a million miles away, but I doubt I would've got it working in less than 6 months by myself :)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
for /r "w:\Data\Corporations\555" %%a in (*.zip) do for %%b in ("%%~dpa.") do md "%%~dpbConcat" 2>nul & move /y "%%~fa" "%%~dpbConcat"
```

Comment: Thanks Endoro, that would be great for just the w:\Data\Corporations\555 folder, but I need to process a lot of other folders within Corporations too. @dbenham's answer below does exactly that. I'm still very new to all of this though, and the more examples I see the better my understanding is, so thanks for that :)